# Update text to show variable

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I've got a variable displayed on screen and would like to have this update whenever something happens to it.

I thought I had it solved by using this:

```
local function updateCredits( event )
    creditsText = display.newText(credits, 400, 0, native.systemFont, 36)
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", updateCredits )
```

But this just redraws the text every time (I should've seen that one coming). Is there any way I can update text in a way that doesnt require me deleting the old instance and placing in a new one?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by using creditsText.text = credits which updates the existing text.

Answer (score 0):

Every text created in Corona with newText have a property called text. It represents the text which will be shown on screen. Changing it will update its appearance on screen.